# Strange Tomcat characterset translations

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jakarta-mail

Can't figure this out. When my tomcat app sends emails (Javamail API), The '$' gets replaced with '¤'...

Only on Linux. On Windows it works fine.

I've got UTF-8s and locale EN all over the place - in the Javamail code, on every page, in the app config. I would have thought the $ would be ascii enough not to have character set problems.

e.g.

```
Each    Price
¤99.97  ¤99.97
Subtotal:   ¤99.97
Shipping:   ¤10.00
```

Can anyone suggest where else to look? I'm suspecting it's not charset or locale... And again, it's only from the Linux server...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you send a simple message with a literal "$" in the message content, coming from a Java String object, does it still fail?  For example, msg.setText("test $1").  What do you see if you use msg.writeTo(new FileOutputStream("msg.txt"))?

What version of JavaMail are you using.  Some versions of Linux include the GNU version of JavaMail, which sometimes has problems.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The literals $s were okay. It turned out to be the formatNumber tags.

I had set the page charset...

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

But has forgotten to set the locale for the taglib.

```
<fmt:setLocale value="en_US" scope="session"/>

<fmt:formatNumber value="${row.price}" type="currency"/>
```

Thanks for your help.